# "She picked up the male [puppet], examined the thick wooden handle with the finger grooves." p.388 Gone Girl by Gillian Flynn

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, vocabulary

I have a short question,
finger grooves? Can somebody explain or try to explain what the author meant? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the handle had indentations for the fingers to create a tighter grip. The handles of utility knives and hunting knives (like buck knives) often have [finger grooves](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/50/de/6e/50de6e414f60bffab55530c3aa0601c4.jpg).

Comment: Thank you so much, Sarah! Your explanation is more than adequate.